# I'm Plotting the output voltage of RLC circuit and I'm not sure how to input the formula

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy

Our homework is to plot the voltage across a 1-Ohm Resistor, 120mH Inductor, and 1µF Capacitor, given a 1000 Hz cosine wave with peak-to-peak current of 1 mA.

So I already got down on how to plot the input voltage the cosine wave. The challenge is putting the formulas for resistor voltage, inductor voltage and capacitor voltage into code.

---

```
def v_cap(x,c):
    VC = ((1/c)*integrate.quad(lambda k: (x), k_low,k_high) + v_cap(x=0,c=0.000001))
    return VC
for i in x_time:
    y_vC[i]=v_cap[i][0]
    i+=1
```

---

Exception has occurred: TypeError
'function' object is not subscriptable
  File "Del2", line 48, in 
    y_vC[i]=v_cap[i][0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `()` your function:

```
y_vC[i]=v_cap()[i][0]
```